# How do I create a url randomizer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want -

Javascript url randomizer that executes when an image is clicked. I don't want the browser to navigate to a different page, I want the random url to load in an iframe. How would I make a randomizer (some random urls - http://www.google.com , http://www.yahoo.com , http://www.stackoverflow.com)?

Edit - So with this

```
var urls=['url1.com','url2.com','url3.com']; 
var randomURL = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
myframe = get("myframe")
myframe.src = Math.random;
```

it will navigate to a random url in the iframe? (btw the iframe's name is myframe)

Comment: That would require having a database of random URLs

Comment: That would be `myFrame.src = randomUrl`, not `myFrame.src = Math.random`.

Comment: What you want for the last two lines is `document.getElementById('myframe').src=randomURL;`

Answer (score 0):

Store the URLs in an array. On the event, pick a random URL using the `random` method.

```
var urls = ['1', '2', '3'];
function onClick() { 
   var randomUrl = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)];

   alert(randomUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a list of random URLs in an array and then use `Math.random` to get an index for the array to return a random url.

```
var urls=['url1.com','url2.com','url3.com']; 
var randomURL = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/UMQUw/

```
var links = ['http://microsoft.com', 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://bing.com'];
function loadRandomUrl() {
    var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
    frame.src = links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Randomly selecting a URL may return the same URL two (or more) times in a row. Also, a visitor may not visit all URLs equally if selecting at random a number of times.

To ensure they never get the same URL twice in a row, and visit each URL an equal number of times, consider something like:

```
var getRandomURL = (function() {
    var oUrls = ['http://www.a.com','http://www.b.com','http://www.c.com'];
    var urls = [];
    var previous;

    return function() {

     if (!urls.length) urls = oUrls.slice(0);

      var i = Math.random()*urls.length | 0; 

      if (urls[i] == previous) return getRandomURL();

      previous = urls.splice(i, 1);

      return previous;
    };
}());
```